# How to call files for .py program without having to define entire path

Tags: python, command-line

```
   Signature_1=(input('Name.txt:'))#"/Users/Owner/Desktop/x.txt"
```

Edit: Overall I would just like to get the name of file "x". Is there a generic approach that I can use to extract just the file name from the path and store it under a separate variable to be called later?

The above line when ran in command prompt requires that I input the entire file path. The input will be used in the program later to title graphs, so I would like to exclude the entire path and just get the file name. Is there a simple way to do this command prompt? I am used to working in jupyter which is much smoother for these kind of tasks. Thank you in advance

Comment: how exactly are you running that piece of code in the command line?

Comment: I am running a .py program and that is the first line in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can just move the files to my directory and call them by name.

Answer (score 1):

you can drop your file to cmd, but it seems impossible to not put the entire path to open the file